# Original source for Littlewood’s three precepts of refereeing in mathematics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ho.history-overview, journals, peer-review

I have a question regarding Littlewood’s three precepts of refereeing a mathematical paper, namely whether it is (1) new, (2) correct, and (3) interesting.

I have found these mentioned in the literature on refereeing, e.g.:

- “you should address Littlewoods’s three precepts: (1) Is it new? (2) Is it correct? Is it surprising?” (Krantz, 1997, p. 125); or
- “the fundamental precepts ‘Is it true?’, ‘Is it new?’, and ‘Is it interesting?’ to which, Littlewood believed, a referee should always respond.” (Moslehian, 2010: 1245)

Unfortunately, I haven’t been able to track down the original source.  Does anyone know where Littlewood might have formulated these three precepts?

Thank you!

REFERENCES

Krantz, S. G. (1997). *A Primer of Mathematical Writing: Being a Disquisition on Having Your Ideas Recorded, Typeset, Published, Read, and Appreciated*. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society.

Moslehian, M. S. (2010). Attributes of an ideal referee. Notices of the American Mathematical Society, 57 (10), 1245. ([pdf](http://www.ams.org/notices/201010/rtx101001245p.pdf))

Answer (score 35):

According to [Ralph Boas,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_P._Boas_Jr.) in his memoir [Lion Hunting and Other Mathematical Pursuits](https://books.google.nl/books?id=f-EWj5WtQHgC) (page 10), it was not Littlewood but [G.H. Hardy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._H._Hardy) who asked these three questions to referees, as editor of the Journal of the London Mathematical Society. This is given as a first-hand recollection, so probably reliable:

[image]

Comment: I knew, no one else but you, would find the answer. You should be hired by Google to improve their search algorithms!

Comment: I wish I could upvote the quote as well as the answer!

Comment: I don't see anything here ruling out the possibility that Hardy got the idea from Littlewood.

Answer (score 8):

That's fantastic.  With that new information, I was able to find that Paul Halmos (1985: 119) also attributes this to Hardy:

[image]

Halmos, P. R. (1985). *I Want to Be A Mathematician: An Automathography.* New York: Springer.